# Pandas: transpose dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, transpose

I have df:

```
ID  url visits  count_sec   buys
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136    aliexpress.com  3438    33067   25
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136    ebay.com    9   44  
001342afb153e2775649dc5ae0460605    ozon.ru 1   6   
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3    aliexpress.com  24  2196    
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3    bonprix.ru  42  1378
```

I need to transponse it and get

```
ID                                         url
                                    visits  count_sec   buys
                                  aliexpress.com         ebay.com            ozon.ru     aliexpress.com      bonprix.ru
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136   3438 33067 25       9    44    0        0    0    0        0   0   0          0   0   0
001342afb153e2775649dc5ae0460605    0   0   0           0   0   0          1    6    0        0   0   0          0   0   0
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3    0   0   0           0   0   0          0   0    0       24  2196  0         42  1378   0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need top `url` in Multiindex in columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), but there is missing top `url` in `MultiIndex` in columns. Also values are only random, because it is not clear which each column contain values:

```
#new column with value `url`
df['url1'] = 'url'
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', values=['visits','count_sec','buys'],columns=['url1','url'])
#swap first and second level in MultiIndex in columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
#remove columns names
df1 = df1.rename_axis((None,None,None), axis=1)
print (df1)
                                            url                              \
                                         visits                               
                                 aliexpress.com bonprix.ru ebay.com ozon.ru   
ID                                                                            
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136         3438.0        NaN      NaN     NaN   
001342afb153e2775649dc5ae0460605            NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN   
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3            NaN        NaN      NaN     NaN   

                                                                             \
                                      count_sec                               
                                 aliexpress.com bonprix.ru ebay.com ozon.ru   
ID                                                                            
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136        33067.0        NaN      9.0     NaN   
001342afb153e2775649dc5ae0460605            NaN        NaN      NaN     1.0   
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3           24.0       42.0      NaN     NaN   


                                           buys                              
                                 aliexpress.com bonprix.ru ebay.com ozon.ru  
ID                                                                           
0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136           25.0        NaN     44.0     NaN  
001342afb153e2775649dc5ae0460605            NaN        NaN      NaN     6.0  
0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3         2196.0     1378.0      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Is it real to do `url` at the top and `visits, count_sec, buys` under that?

Comment: And I asked question about `merge` df. you asked me `result = pd.merge(short, short1, on='ID', how='outer')
`. but how can I merge `pivot table`?

Comment: If need merge with another dataframe by `print (pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), short, on='ID', how='outer'))`, you need remove Multiindex, because warning: `C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py:205: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (3 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)`